# Задание на определение оборудования

Tags: ассемблер

Надо проверить наличие поддержки в процессоре виртуального процессора 8086. Помогите, очень срочно надо, скоро сдавать. Без понятия как делать.

Comment: а что же вы на лекциях делали (если вообще ходили на них)?

Comment: вот что вам нужно походу: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register

Comment: @Умка, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я человек который не пропускает занятия. мы дисциплину ассемблер отдельно не изучали. т.е по учебному плану не проходили. это задание по Организации ЭВМ, там не объясняли про процессоры 8086.

Answer (score 2):

```
pushfd           ; размещение регистра EFLAGS в стеке
pop eax          ; извлечение значения EFLAGS в EAX
mov ebx, eax     ; сохранение значения в EBX
xor eax, 200000h ; изменение 21-го бита
push eax         ; размещение нового значения в стеке
popfd            ; сохранение нового значения в EFLAGS
pushfd           ; снова размещение EFLAGS в стеке
pop eax          ; значение EFLAGS теперь в EAX
xor eax, ebx     ; проверка 21-го бита
je no_cpuid      ; если он не изменился, то CPUID не поддерживается
```